# Loading txt file on Android with Harman 50.2.4.2

Tags: sdk, air, android-update-sdk, harman

I have a little problem since december 2023. I updated my SDK to Harman's 50.2.4.2, because my app on android device is now recognized as "to old" (don't know the english translation, I have a french version) to be supported, since an update of my device (Android 14). Well, I can install it now and it can be launched, but...I have local files on my device, usually loaded in the app. It works fine on Air for Desktop 50.2.4.2, but the files doesn't seem to be loaded anymore on the Android version.

Here is my Folder declaration, which contains my .txt files to load:

```
TEXTS = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Documents/Seeds/DONNEES/Texts");
```

All permissions in the xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

If anyone has an idea ?